# I can't select directly from a table I created

Tags: oracle-10g, plsql

My client created a user in his Oracle instance for me to install the objects I have created in my local instance. However, this strange behavior prevents me to deliver my project. I guess it's a security/role related issue, but can't figure out what's missing:

```
CREATE TABLE "test"(A NUMBER);  -- WORKS FINE

SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'test'; -- WORKS FINE, object exists

SELECT * FROM test; -- ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I need to point out the exact missing configuration to my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer! Took me less than I expected. The script that created the table quoted the table name, so the only way to find the table in a select statement was quoting the name.

Same problem posted here:

[What exactly do quotation marks around the table name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do) (Stack Overflow)